# Django: return json only for api sub-app

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    url(r'^subapp1/', include('subapp1.urls', namespace='subapp1')),
    url(r'^api/', include('api.urls')),
)
```

When `GET /api/invalid/url` sent, 404 html page returned. It seems that this is not right for REST APIs.

How to make invalid urls starting with `subapp1/` return 404 html page, and make invalid urls starting with `api/` return 404 status code and error message in json?

Is it possible to set Django to return default response based on `Accept` field in the request header? e.g. return 404 html, if `Accept text/html`, return json if `Accept application/json`

Any comments welcomed. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May the following piece of codes help.

From the source codes of [django.views.defaults](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/defaults.py#L56), `http.HttpResponseNotFound(body, content_type=content_type)` should be returned. So, checking `request.path`, if starting with `/topApp/api`, return `http.HttpResponseNotFound(body, content_type='application/json')`, otherwise, return `default` response.

Always, `request.path` starts with `/topApp`, not IP nor hostname. And input parameters (see [link](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/defaults.py#L17)) include `request, exception, template_name=ERROR_404_TEMPLATE_NAME`, which should be handled by `*args, **kwargs` in my codes.

```
from django.views.defaults import page_not_found 

    def customized_page_not_found(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.path.startswith('/topApp/api'):
            try:    
                from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound
                return HttpResponseNotFound( json.dumps( {'error': 'Page Not Found'} ),
                        content_type='application/json')
            except Exception as e:
                pass
                # handle exception here

        return page_not_found( request, *args, **kwargs)


handler404 = customized_page_not_found
```

Any questions and comments welcomed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the resulted response is 200. you should add `status=404` to `HTTPResponseNotFound` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: checks both url and content type

my_project/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include, handler404
from my_app import views

handler404 = views.page_not_found
```

my_app/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound, JsonResponse

def page_not_found(request):
    if request.get_full_path()[1:].startswith('api') and request.content_type == 'application/json':
        return JsonResponse({'not': 'found'})
    return HttpResponseNotFound('Not found')
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views

Comment: how to check the `content type`? Thanks